# Objective-C - Show avatar picture from XMPPvCardAvatarModule in XEP 153?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmpp

I'm developing an iphone app with XMPP.

I'm trying to print the images of the logged in users in the chat room. This is the code I have.

```
XMPPvCardAvatarModule *avatar = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc]initWithvCardTempModule:[[self appDelegate]xmppvCardTempModule]];
XMPPJID *jidUser = [XMPPJID jidWithString:key];
NSData *foto = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:[avatar photoDataForJID:jidUser]];UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageWithData:fotoData];
UIImageView *picVista = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic];

[self.commentsGente addSubview:picVista];
```

But that NSData is always 0KB, so there's obviously no image. How to do this?

Comment: hey bro i need your help in v-cards. can u tell how to implement or save the cards and how to retrieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule]photoDataForJID:user.jid];

UIImageView *picVista;
picVista.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
```

try this it works fine for me